# Can I use my school ID card for an Indian domestic flight?

Tags: india, paperwork, identity-cards, goair

[image: Image of student ID]

The only ID card I have is for my 7th year class. Can I use it as ID for domestic flight from LKO-DEL?

I am traveling with my father; he have all documents, so can I get verified by him ?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I have replaced your original image with one that obscures your personal information; for your own safety and privacy, I would strongly advise against posting personal information such as your address and telephone on the Internet.

Comment: I only have admit card can i use it at jet konnect Lucknow to Mumbai

Answer (score 8):

In India you usually need to show your ID at two places -  entrance to the airport and at check-in.

As per [this news item](http://www.livemint.com/Politics/zqFqn2M8dkM4RgMoUG9OHM/Mobile-Aadhaar-can-be-used-as-ID-proof-to-enter-airports-BC.html), Bureau of Civil Aviation expects passengers to have any one of the following IDs to enter the airport:

> 1. Passport
> 2. Voter ID
> 3. Aadhaar or m-Aadhaar
> 4. Pan Card
> 5. Driving licence
> 6. Service ID
> 7. **Student ID card**
> 8. Passbook of account in a nationalised bank with photo
> 9. Pension card or pension documents with photo
> 10. Disability ID card or handicapped medical certificate

So your student ID should be sufficient. But the same report also states

> BCAS also clarified that infants or **minors accompanied by a guardian with a valid ID wouldn't need a separate proof** for domestic air travel. Unaccompanied minors would.

As you are travelling with your father (a bona fide passenger) you won't need to produce any proof.

For check-in the student ID should be sufficient (if the staff at all ask for it). Links for [Air India](http://www.airindia.in/documents-to-carry.htm), [Indigo](https://www.goindigo.in/travel-information/en/travel-documents.all.html), [goair](https://www.goair.in/terms-conditions)

Comment: Thanks, this just resolved a big problem of mine.